# Word VBA: Invalidate IRibbon on Selection Change (To Achieve the behavior of Bold Toggle Button)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to achieve the same behavior of a toggle button like the Bold button. The ribbon has Toggle Buttons to Assign Styles. When the User  places the cursor for example in a paragraph with style "Custom_Heading_1" the Toggle Button for "Custom_Heading_1" should set the pressed state to true.

Here a short code example:

XML:

```
<customUI 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" 
onLoad="InitializeRibbon">
...
<toggleButton id="customToggle" label="Ü1" 
              onAction="FormatControl" getPressed="IsPressed" />
...
```

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oRibbon As IRibbonUI

Private Sub InitializeRibbon(ByVal Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set oRibbon = Ribbon
End Sub

Private Sub IsPressed(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef pressed)

    If Selection.Style = "Custom_Heading_1" Then
        pressed = True
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub ResetTest()
    oRibbon.InvalidateControl ("customToggle")
End Sub
```

This works fine, but now I have to trigger ResetTest() when the cursor moves or is placed in a paragraph etc.

I think I need something like an Event of the Selection Object to call ResetTest() every time the selection is changed. Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

The Word.Application has some events which can be used by defining a class module which handles the events. The Event which fires when the selection moves is "WindowSelectionChange".

clsEvents:

```
Public WithEvents evEvents As Word.Application

Private Sub evEvents_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)

    oRibbon.Invalidate

End Sub
```

Than I have to create an instance when starting Word. This can be done in an AutoExec Module with a Sub called Main() or in ThisDocument a Sub called AutoExec.

Module AutoExec:

```
Dim oApp As New clsEvents

Sub Main()

    Set oApp.evEvents = Word.Application

End Sub
```

The fact that the oRibbon Variable is Public and accessed inside the Sub of the class module is not very nice. But it works.